# Retrieved image from sqlitedatabse has very bad quality loaded to listview android

Tags: android

I converted image to byte and saved to database, also retrieved it from database and loaded it to the listview .Everything works fine ,but the image which is displayed on the listview has very poor quality ,though the original image has good quality

SearchViewBinder.java

```
public class SearchViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder, ViewBinder{

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(view instanceof ImageView)
        {
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;
            ImageView iv=(ImageView) view;
            byte[] img=cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }

}
```

list_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <!-- THUMBAIL IMAGE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

SearchListActivity.java

```
public class SearchListActivity extends ListActivity {

    String from[];
    int to[];
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;



    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_list_activity);
        Cursor cursor;
        CursorLoader cursorLoader=new CursorLoader(this,BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null,null);
        cursor=cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        from=new String[]{BirthdayProvider.PHOTO,BirthdayProvider.NAME,BirthdayProvider.NUMBER,BirthdayProvider.CATEGORY,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DAY,BirthdayProvider.TURNS_AGE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_WEEK,BirthdayProvider.WESTERN_ZODIAC,BirthdayProvider.DAYS_REMAINING};
        to=new int[]{R.id.list_image,R.id.title_name,R.id.sub_title_contact_number,R.id.sub_title_category,R.id.txtview_type_of_reminder,R.id.sub_title_birthdate,R.id.txtview_turns,R.id.txtview_next_bd,R.id.txtview_zodiac,R.id.txtview_days_left};
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
            adapter.setViewBinder(new SearchViewBinder());
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Image converted to Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getContactImage(Context context,ContentResolver cr,String id){
      Uri contactUri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(id));

        InputStream inputStream=ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);
        if (inputStream==null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.no_photo_placeholder);
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
  }
```

Bitmap converted to byte array

```
public static byte[] convertImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0,outputStream);
      return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }
```

Comment: Where do you save the image? Post that code, so we can figure out if you compress it too much while saving.

Comment: @karthik what are you gong here? Don't be said like this. If you have a problem with your question then just wait for response otherwise remove this question.

Comment: @Tim Kranen-----pls see my updated code

Comment: @Neil Don't demoralize the person. If you think you can guide him in better way then do that. No need to use slang words here.

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta ------ don't mistake me ...I just replied to  @Neil

Comment: If you are downloading images from URL, its better to store on storage and just have a path to that image stored in database.

Comment: @shree202---no Sir, I am fetching the image from contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're compressing the image with the quality parameter set to 0. Try 100 instead. If you save the image as a .png the quality parameter doesn't matter, but with a JPEG compression it does.

```
public static byte[] convertImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
  return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

}

Comment: It gives me same result with option set to 100 , or CompressFormat.PNG  without considering options

Comment: Are you 100% positive that the original image (obtained with .getBlob()) is a high quality one?

Comment: @karthik Curious, was it just the parameter?

Comment: I tried to change the contact image with another good quality one , and then it worked...I I want to retrieve two image how should I alter SearchViewBinder.java ,because it handle only one imageview

Comment: I think you need to ask a seperate question for that, I've never worked with such a pattern (SearchViewBinder) before.